# How can I add a video in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Can you add a local video(mov) to a Markdown file (md)?

I have tried: `[![Video](file:video.mov)`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Depending on your markdown processor, there may be a built-in syntax. For example, in pandoc [the image syntax](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#images) with a video file extension (`.mov`, `.mp4`) can be used:

```
![](my_video.mov)
```

For other processors, you can always write raw-HTML in your markdown:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is correct, but if you're dealing with GitHub, now you can just [add a URL to the video](https://github.blog/2021-05-13-video-uploads-available-github/) and it will automatically be embedded, as long as it's surrounded by empty lines. For example:

```
# cool-beans

https://example.com/video.mp4

Press play to see the video.
```

Answer (score 2):

[fregante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288906/fregante)'s answer works fine for videos you upload to GitHub yourself, but not for youtube video links.

[mb21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214446/mb21)'s answer works fine for links if you want to provide the image yourself, but that means you'll have to use the plain thumbnail image without the play button (in which case it doesn't look like a video), or edit an image yourself, which is time-consuming.

In case you wanna get the thumbnail from a video on the web automatically... you can use an API I made which essentially gets the video's thumbnail, then adds a play button and backdrop to it.

### You can use it in markdown like this:

```
[![](https://markdown-videos-api.jorgenkh.no/youtube/{video_id})](https://youtu.be/{video_id})
```

Clicking on the image will open the video in your browser.

### Demo:

```
[![](https://markdown-videos-api.jorgenkh.no/youtube/dQw4w9WgXcQ)](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ)
```

[image]

GitHub repo and documentation can be found here -> https://github.com/Snailedlt/Markdown-Videos

### Edit

I've now made a simple website that generates the code for you: https://markdown-videos.jorgenkh.no/

Answer (score 0):

For GitHub markdown (in website), you can drag the video file from your file explorer and drop it into the comment or text box.

This action will automatically generate a URL and store it in GitHub Assets.